# Creating a custom page to manipulate data on elgg

Tags: php, crud, elgg

I'm new to Elgg development. Until now I've just customized the appearance. But now I want new entities to interact, one of it is "Organization"  and other is "Product". And for those entities I have to create a page to register new organization, update and delete it. The same for "Product" entity.

Is it possible to do?
Is there a way to create a page (accessing only if the user have permission to) and manipulate the entity data?
Does anybody has a sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend checking out a few Elgg's tutorials:

http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Tutorials

This one in particular:

http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Tutorials/Blog

You can follow that verbatim, but instead of creating 'blog' objects, create your 'product' objects, ie:

```
...
$product = new ElggObject();
$product->subtype = "product";
$product->title = $title;
$product->description = $body;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create any entities easily in Elgg. Check the Elgg blog tutorial mentioned above. Also it will be better if you ask these sorts of questions in the Elgg community.